# Compiling .cu using nvcc in cmake

Tags: c++11, cuda, cmake, nvcc

I have an opencv c++ script and I need to use cudamemcpy in it. So I used cudamemcpy in my script and saved the file as a .cu I am using cmake. So I added the .cu as a cuda_executable. But when I use "sudo make" I get the following error

[image: error I get]

This is the makefile
[image: cmakelists.txt]

So in line 27 I changed c++0x to c++11 and I got the same error
so I tried gnu++11 but I still have the same error.

Comment: You don't need to use a .cu extension for the source if all you are doing is calling functions from the runtime API. Also, please don't post error text and code as images. Search doesn't work with images

Comment: There is a generation of engineers that never knew dialup modems.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `-std=c++11` is not added to the `nvcc` build command if it is passed via `add_definitions()`. From the [FindCUDA cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindCUDA.html):

> Flags passed into add_definitions with -D or /D are passed along to nvcc.

Other options like `-std=c++11` are not passed to `nvcc`.

You can enable `c++11` globally by adding it to the `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS`

```
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )
```

Or on a per target level with

```
cuda_add_executable(opencv opencv.cu OPTIONS -std=c++11)
```

---

As talonmies pointed out in the comment: if you only need functions from the runtime API, like `cudaMemcpy()`, you can use them in ordinary C++-files (no .cu extension required). Then, you need to include `cuda_runtime_api.h` and link to the cuda runtime library `cudart`. (Ensure that the cuda include directory is on your include-path and the library in your library path, which is automatically taken care of if you used `nvcc` to compile.)

---

#### Update

The proper way to set the c++ standard for more recent versions of CMake is explained here: [Triggering C++11 support in NVCC with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551469/triggering-c11-support-in-nvcc-with-cmake)