# Triggering C++11 support in NVCC with CMake

Tags: c++11, cuda, cmake

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 with CUDA 7.5. CMmake is v3.2.2, NVCC is release 7.5, v7.5.17; GCC is Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2 v5.2.1

Triggering C++11 in regular projects is easy with:

```
project(foo CXX)
set(TARGET foo CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

I'm defining my CUDA project with:

```
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(foo ${foo_src} ${foo_hdr} ${foo_cu})
```

But the C++11 support doesn't get propagated to NVCC. I have to add:

```
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
```

This seems like a kludge. There was evidently work on this recently according to [this task](http://redmine.gromacs.org/issues/1390), but I haven't been able to find the results.

How do I get CMake to automatically set the C++11 flags when declaring the project as C++11?

EDIT: I've retuned to to this question with CUDA 8.0 and CMake 3.5.1.

From the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/FindCUDA.html),  `set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)` will propagate the contents of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, so the following triggers C++11 for both cpp and nvcc:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "--std=c++11")
set (CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)
```

However, `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` does not impact `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, so the following gives compiler errors for C++11 device code, as there's nothing to propagate:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)
```

I can't seem to find a combination of CMake commands that avoids explicitly setting `--std=c++11` in either CXX or CUDA flags.

Comment: try setting CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS to ON (although it is suposed to be ON by default) and then set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS with -std=c++11.

Comment: Tried setting CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS to ON. Didn't work.

The command set(TARGET foo CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) already triggers C++11 support in the compiler. Seems redundant to add set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11") on top of that.

Comment: I think this functionality depends on your cmake version. In my case with cmake 3.5.0 setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` with `-std=c++11` and having `CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS` automatically triggers cmake to add `--std c++11` (to nvcc).

Comment: I updated to CMake 3.5.1 and have been looking at FindCUDA.cmake. I'm printing the value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS after setting CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD to 11 and am surprised that it's empty. Am I wrong to think that CMake should populate it based on the value of CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD and other variables?

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is the place to file bug reports or feature requests for the cmake modules, try their dedicated bug tracker.

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus: So, what did you do about this eventually?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus The same problems. CMake 3.10.0 and CUDA 9.0.

Answer (score 7):

Since CMake 3.8 (since CMake supports CUDA as a language) there is a new target property [CUDA_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/prop_tgt/CUDA_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CUDA_STANDARD). Although its name is quite confusing, it adds the `-std=XXX` to the `nvcc` compile command.

With a recent CMake version the proper way would be

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8.2)
enable_language(CUDA)
add_executable(foo ${foo_src} ${foo_cu})
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY CUDA_STANDARD 11)
```